# Unable to locate package mongodb-org

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

I'm not able to install mongoDB on my ubuntu 22.04

```
~$ sudo apt-get update

~$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
```

Then I tried this

```
~$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package mongodb is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mongodb' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have maybe missed the point with the repo , check the exact steps [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

For mongoDB 5.0 it is expected to create this apt list:

```
 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list
```

as follow:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list
```

and then executing:

```
 sudo  apt update
```

So the new repo to be considered ...

Answer (score 0):

it is because

```
 mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
```

to fix this you have to install `libssl1.1`

so , i found i solution to fix it just type the following command

Step - 1 : Open Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)
Step - 2 : type `sudo -s` press enter and type your root password 
Step - 3 : type `sudo -i` and press enter
Step - 4 : type `wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb` and press enter
Step - 5 : type `sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb` and press enter

You have successfully installed `libssl1.1` and you can go to install mongodb by typing : `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb`